# Correct way, working with Images .Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, image-processing

I'm currently working on a project, where I need to be able to store images that the admin provides.

Imagine a blogpost that contains like 4 pictures.
How would I save them? 
Where would I save them?
Datatypes??
I'm currently using an SQL database.

There will be MAX 100 pictures, so it will not be a huge amount.

But the user clicks on "upload image" and uploads like 4 images. Then it should save. 
Now on the index page these pictures would show.

I've never worked with images before, that's why all of these rookie questions.

Comment: How about doing a little search?: https://www.bing.com/search?q=upload+imgaes+in+asp.net+core